About magnetic forces on a current carrying wire
so im studying this and it says that there are two forces, 1- one that affects the copper wire (Fb=ILB) and 2- one that affects the magnets.
i understand where the first one came from but i dont know what is the second one
it says that these two forces are equal and so i dont need to do much calculations but WHERE DID IT COME FROM, idk .


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"it says that these two forces are equal". They are equal and opposite, as Newton's third law demands. But Jos Bergervoet explains in terms of electromagnetism how the force on the magnet comes about.

The current through the wire creates a magnetic field with strength:$$|B|=\frac{\mu_0\, I}{2\pi\,r} $$ at distance $r$. The magnets feel a force because they are in that field. This is difficult to compute (it would basically  be the force felt by a magnetic dipole in a given magnetic field) but as you already mention we know that this force has to be opposite the other one that has already been computed.

"... in a given magnetic field ..." In a given non-uniform field?

About as non-uniform as I gave it (see Eqn. in the answer). Indeed this is important if you actually want to compute the force (although, as argued repeatedly, that is not immediately needed here, unless of course OP changes the question.)
